# Change x axes scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created this plot using Matlab

[image]

Using matplotlib, the x-axies draws large numbers such as 100000, 200000, 300000. I would like to have something like  1, 2, 3 and a 10^5 to indicate that it's actually 100000, 200000, 300000.

Is there a simple way to create such scale in matplotlib?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Try using [`matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0))
```

This applies scientific notation (i.e. `a x 10^b`) to your x-axis tickmarks

Comment: is it possible to add an offset? (e.g. instead of 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, ... and x 10^b it will be 0, 5, 10, 15,... and x 10^{b-1})

Comment: `ticklabel_format` is also a method for the axes objects, you can try something like
`ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0))`

Comment: How can this work if you have a subplot of, say, 2 plots?

Comment: @Eagle sorry, your follow-up question about adding an offset was what I was referring to. my x-axis is `[0.1, 0.2, ...]` and I'd prefer `[1, 2, ...]` with an adjusted exponent. were you able to find a solution for that?

Comment: @Eagle I am also interested in the question trianta2 mentioned

Comment: For he behaviour asked about here by @trianta2 to have a fixed order of magnititude for the exponent see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656139/set-scientific-notation-with-fixed-exponent-and-significant-digits-for-multiple).

Comment: Hint: use option `UseMathText=True` to get math notation instead of `1e6`

Comment: Hint full version: `plt.gca().ticklabel_format(useMathText=True)` 
and magnitude will be displayed as the number 10

Answer (score 19):

This is not so much an answer to your original question as to one of the queries you had in the body of your question.

A little preamble, so that my naming doesn't seem strange:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import rc
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
ax = self.figure.add_subplot( 111 )
```

As has been mentioned you can use ticklabel_format to specify that matplotlib should use scientific notation for large or small values:

```
ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci',scilimits=(-3,4),axis='both')
```

You can affect the way that this is displayed using the flags in rcParams (from matplotlib import rcParams) or by setting them directly. I haven't found a more elegant way of changing between '1e' and 'x10^' scientific notation than:

```
ax.xaxis.major.formatter._useMathText = True
```

This should give you the more Matlab-esc, and indeed arguably better appearance. I think   the following should do the same:

```
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

Answer (score 12):

The [scalar formatter](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter) supports collecting the exponents.  The docs are as follows:

> class matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=True,
>   useMathText=False, useLocale=None) Bases: matplotlib.ticker.Formatter
>
> Tick location is a plain old number. If useOffset==True and the data
>   range is much smaller than the data average, then an offset will be
>   determined such that the tick labels are meaningful. Scientific
>   notation is used for data < 10^-n or data >= 10^m, where n and m are
>   the power limits set using set_powerlimits((n,m)). The defaults for
>   these are controlled by the axes.formatter.limits rc parameter.

your technique would be:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
xfmt = ScalarFormatter()
xfmt.set_powerlimits((-3,3))  # Or whatever your limits are . . .
{{ Make your plot }}
gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
```

To get the exponent displayed in the format `x10^5`, instantiate the ScalarFormatter with `useMathText=True`.

[image: After Image]

You could also use:

```
xfmt.set_useOffset(10000)
```

To get a result like this:

[image]

Comment: Instantiate the ScalarFormatter with `useMathText=True` to get `x10^4`.

Answer (score 8):

I find the simple solution

```
pylab.ticklabel_format(axis='y',style='sci',scilimits=(1,4))
```