# How to put power of 10 formats not like 1e-5 at axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

If we use scientific notation for plotting data as you know usually `1e{+b}` would be noted on top of axes. I would like to put `10^{b}` instead of the notations of `1e{+b}`. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could use `matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter`, try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
xs = np.logspace(1,10,10)

ax.plot(xs,range(10))
ax.set_xscale('log')

#the next line is generally wrong, it works just as an example
#ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FuncFormatter(lambda value,pos: ("$10^{%d}$" % pos) ))

#this way change the ticks formats
#import math
#ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FuncFormatter(lambda v,_: ("$10^{%d}$" % math.log(v,10)) ))

#maybe this is what you want
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True))

plt.show()
```

The above example will render as latex but if you prefer to show the '^' symbol just use `"10^{%d}" % pos` on your function.

Comment: There is also http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter which does exactly this without needing to define a lambda (and there will be a version for new-style format strings in 1.4)

Comment: @tcaswell Yes, but with `FormatStrFormatter` I got the value of the tick, no? I've used the position as a more easy example (I don't have to make any calculation), this `FormatStrFormatter("$10^{%d}$")` will not work (at least on my version of matplotlib [1.2.1]).

Comment: yeah, your are correct.  The format string formatter is only useful when you can beat what you want into a format string.  Now that I read your answer more carefully, it is very wrong.   You should not trust the `pos` value and do `10^{%d}"% log(val))`.  If the user changes the view limits the ticks will not change. (it won't let my take my +1 back.....)

Comment: Yes I know that's wrong as a general solution but I just wanted to show a simple example (thats why I've names the params with long names not just `v,p`), first I was typing the math calculations with value but finally I just post the example with `pos`. I will update my answer.

Comment: It maybe a simple example, but it is a _dangerous_ simple example.

Comment: Thank you so much xndrme and tcaswell. I tried xndrme's suggestion but it was different from what I want. I'm sorry for the misleading question. I want to put 10^{} at the top of the axes not as tick mark labels. I don't want to use log tick marks either.  I would apologize if you already answered my question...I mean if I could achieve with a small modification of your the first answer.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577665/change-x-axes-scale-in-matplotlib here they placed scientific notations nicely but the formats was the 1e{} style. I just want to change this to 10^{} style.

Comment: Do you want the '^' symbol to be rendered or you accept latex rendering? I've updated my answer, hope it helps now :)

Comment: Exactly!Thanks a lot xndrme.