# matplotlib: format axis ticks without offset

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to format my ticks to a certain number of significant figures, AND remove the automatic offset. For the latter I am using https://stackoverflow.com/a/6654046/1021819, and for the former I would use https://stackoverflow.com/a/25750438/1021819, i.e.

```
y_formatter = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(y_formatter)
```

and

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.2e'))
```

How do I combine the FormatStrFormatter and useOffset syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FormatStrFormatter` doesn't use an offset, so by using your second format you automatically won't have an offset.

Compare the two subplots in this example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import numpy as np  

fig,(ax1,ax2)=plt.subplots(2)

ax1.plot(np.arange(10000,10010,1))

ax2.plot(np.arange(10000,10010,1))
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.4e'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Playing devil's advocate, what if I DID want an offset under this scheme?

Comment: Using ```yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.FormatStrFormatter('%.4e'))``` worked for me. Do you know why ```plt.plot(x,y);  ax=plt.gca();  ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)``` would NOT remove the offset? Is something more than those three lines needed?