# How to suppress too intelligent scientific axis ticks in pandas plots

Tags: python, pandas, plot, axis-labels, exponential

I am currently plotting several timeseries with pandas, e.g.:

```
2016-05-08 13:59:06.119000    2.000190
2016-05-08 13:59:11.119000    2.000190
2016-05-08 13:59:16.119000    2.000190
2016-05-08 13:59:21.119000    2.000190
2016-05-08 13:59:26.119000    2.000190
2016-05-08 13:59:31.119000    2.000190
2016-05-08 13:59:36.119000    2.000190
2016-05-08 13:59:41.119000    2.000190
2016-05-08 13:59:46.119000    2.000190
2016-05-08 13:59:51.119000    2.000190
2016-05-08 13:59:56.119000    2.000190
2016-05-08 14:00:01.119000    2.000191
2016-05-08 14:00:06.119000    2.000191
2016-05-08 14:00:11.119000    2.000191
2016-05-08 14:00:16.119000    2.000191
```

and pandas is doing some magic to the the ticks of the y-axis and automatically puts exponential factors and a part to sum on top of the graph. Unfortunately this scientific notation is confusing for the audience that is going to interprete the plots. Is there a way to suppress them? I think they can understand the exponential part (1e-7) but the + 2.00012 part should be just added to the ticks if possible. Especially when behind the +part there is a second exponential part it is not clear to them anymore.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750170/can-i-show-decimal-places-and-scientific-notation-on-the-axis-of-a-matplotlib-pl?rq=1 it seems similar

Comment: I also looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results and I found a few ways to display the column values differently but when plotting I am always back to this kind of intelligent label optimization. As specified above I am especially interested in getting rid of the +somenumber part

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot seems to contain the answer I was looking for: I want to suppress the offset not the scientific notation

Comment: testing it, but for the moment I cannot use useOffset=False because it gives me an AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter.
reading http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/newscalarformatter_demo.html by no, feel free to close