# How to convert float notation to power of 10 scientific notation in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, floating-point, legend

In `Python`, I have values given by `0.000001,0.00001,0.0001,....,1.0` stored in `my_Array` (`np.array`). 
For each of these values I need to label a curve in a plot and store it in the legend as `val = 10e-6` instead of `val = 0.000001`.
The second version is automatically stored if I use (for the `i`'th value):

```
matplolib.pyplot.plot(...., label = 'val = ' + str(my_Array[i]))
```

Is there a function converting the float notation to the scientific power of 10 notation?

Comment: This is built into the basic string formatting, try e.g. `format(0.00001, '.0e')`.

Comment: yes, this is the best solution

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may use a combination of a `ScalarFormatter` and a `FuncFormatter` to format your values as mathtext. I.e. instead of 0.01 or 1e-2 it would look like [image].

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

vals = [0.000001,0.00001,0.0001,0.01,1.0]

f = mticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False, useMathText=True)
g = lambda x,pos : "${}$".format(f._formatSciNotation('%1.10e' % x))
fmt = mticker.FuncFormatter(g)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i,val in enumerate(vals):
    ax.plot([0,1],[i,i], label="val = {}".format(fmt(val)))

ax.legend()    
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is essentially the same concept as in [Can I show decimal places and scientific notation on the axis of a matplotlib plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49330649/4124317), just not for the axes, but the legend.

Comment: AttributeError: 'ScalarFormatter' object has no attribute '_formatSciNotation'

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the round between '%.2E%' and the desired number.

```
'%.2E' % Decimal('40800000000.00000000000000')

# returns '4.08E+10'
```

as seen on [Display a decimal in scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913532/display-a-decimal-in-scientific-notation)

The '%.2E%' rounds to the 2nd decimal point. To round to just the first one, use  '%.1E%'.

-

To achieve what you want, just:

```
x = 0.0001
y = '%.2E' % x

print (y)

# prints 1.00E-04
```

(EDITED after jonrsharpe's tip)

Comment: Conversion to `Decimal` is completely unnecessary here, that string format works on any numerical types.

Comment: can you please edit your answer explaining that the '2' is rounding to the second decimal?

Comment: Also *"You can just get the modulus"* is totally wrong, that's **not** what is happening. That's a different usage of the `%` symbol than modulus.

Comment: I'll try to gather some more info and edit my answer, then

Comment: you can add the "format()" method mentioned by @jonrsharpe  in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In theory the below should work without the need to call private functions. However, something is broken in version 3.11 at least such that no check to the power limits is actually done inside ScalarFormatter.

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
f = mticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
f.set_powerlimits((-3,3))
"${}$".format(f.format_data(0.0001))
```