# How does one show x10(superscript number) instead of 1e(number) for axes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scientific-notation

The only way I know how to use scientific notation for the end of the axes in matplotlib is with

plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))

but this will use 1e instead of x10. In the example code below it shows 1e6, but I want x10 to the power of 6, x10superscript6 (x10^6 with the 6 small and no ^). Is there a way to do this?

edit: I do not want scientific notation for each tick in the axis (that does not look good imho), only at the end, like the example shows but with just the 1e6 part altered to x10superscript6.

I can't include images yet.

Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(0,1000)
y = x**2
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I show decimal places and scientific notation on the axis of a matplotlib plot using Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750170/can-i-show-decimal-places-and-scientific-notation-on-the-axis-of-a-matplotlib-pl)

Comment: ImportannceOfBeingErnest showed how to do this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49330649/1678467

Comment: Thanks, but maybe plotting sometimes looked different with python 2.7. I'm not looking for scientific notation on each tick, only at the end of the axis. It's odd I don't see questions about this already though, as I think x10 to the power of something may the default in other programs.

Comment: Are you looking for `plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0), useMathText=True)`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That made the fix on my end.  How you know EVERYTHING about python plotting I don't understand...

Comment: I still get 1e6 with  plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0), useMathText=True)

Comment: @user47014 Which matplotlib version are you using?

Comment: matplotlib.__version__  shows 2.0.2

Comment: I will try updating

Comment: Nevermind, I gave an answer including the case of 2.0.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The offset is formatted differently depending on the `useMathText` argument. If `True` it will show the offset in a latex-like (MathText) format as `x 10^6` instead of `1e6`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(0,1000)
y = x**2
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0), useMathText=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that the above will not work for version 2.0.2 (possibly other older versions). In that case you need to set the formatter manually and specify the option:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(0,1000)
y = x**2
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True))
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Great thanks, that works (I will also update still).

Answer (score 1):

If you need this for all of your plots, you can edit the `rcParams`, for example as follows.

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rc('axes.formatter', use_mathtext=True)
```

Put at at the top of your script. If you want it for *all of your scripts* I recommend looking up matplotlib stylesheets.