# Forcing Scientific Notation and limit Decimals in Matlplotlib using ScalarFormatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks

I have a plot that accepts data with huge differences in scale. To keep the axes clean I am forcing scientific notation so digits don't run off the figure. To do this, I am using ScalarFormatter and adjusting the ticklabel_format like so:

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True, useOffset=False))
ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', scilimits=(0,0), axis='both')
```

The scientific notation is plotted exactly how I want with the exception that too many decimals points can sometimes be displayed.
[The y-axis tick labels are getting clipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d4hv.png)

I found a similar question here: [Show decimal places and scientific notation on the axis of a matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750170/show-decimal-places-and-scientific-notation-on-the-axis-of-a-matplotlib-plot)

But I don't want the exponential factor showing on every label like in the accepted solution. Also, the FormatStrFormatter overwrites my previous ScalarFormatter settings so I think only 1 Formatter can be used.

I would like a plot that always looks like this: [Where the tick labels always limit to 1 decimal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdhsU.png)

Comment: I have the same question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give a particular example of what is exactly displayed in your case.
I personally use the following lines for every axis x/y and it works:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

formatter = mticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
formatter.set_powerlimits((-3,2))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
formatter = mticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
formatter.set_powerlimits((-3,2))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

The `set_powerlimits` setting ensures that only 3 decimal digits after and 2 before a dot are displayed.