# Scientific notation on the axis (literature style) - how to change default font?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, axis-labels, scientific-notation

I need a literature-style scientific notation on both axes in matplotlib with specific font.

In my search I found this question with an answer for literature-style scientific notation from ImportanceOfBeingErnest:
[Show decimal places and scientific notation on the axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750170/show-decimal-places-and-scientific-notation-on-the-axis)

There are no details about changing font though.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=[7,7])

x=np.linspace(0,0.1,10**3)
y=x**2

ax.plot(x,y)

# code from ImportanceOfBeingErnest
class MathTextSciFormatter(mticker.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, fmt="%1.2e"):
        self.fmt = fmt
    def __call__(self, x, pos=None):
        s = self.fmt % x
        decimal_point = '.'
        positive_sign = '+'
        tup = s.split('e')
        significand = tup[0].rstrip(decimal_point)
        sign = tup[1][0].replace(positive_sign, '')
        exponent = tup[1][1:].lstrip('0')
        if exponent:
            exponent = '10^{%s%s}' % (sign, exponent)
        if significand and exponent:
            s =  r'%s{\times}%s' % (significand, exponent)
        else:
            s =  r'%s%s' % (significand, exponent)
        return "${}$".format(s)

# Format with 2 decimal places
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(MathTextSciFormatter("%1.2e"))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(MathTextSciFormatter("%1.2e"))
# end of code from ImportanceOfBeingErnest

plt.xticks(rotation=45,font="Arial",fontsize=20)

for tick in ax.get_yticklabels():
    tick.set_fontname("Arial")
```

Result:
[Graph from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG1wc.png)

The literature-style scientific notation is implemented but none of the two methods of changing font work. Interestingly though, the fontsize can be changed.

Could anyone provide a solution for changing font with this notation?

matplotlib 3.5.3

Comment: Maybe set the font before plotting ?

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. The solution from @Krishnadev N solves it for me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `matplotlib`'s internal mathtext renderer with `r'$...$'` syntax, but you are changing the font only for regular text. You could use

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = 'custom'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.rm']='Arial'
```

to change math fonts everywhere, which is probably what you are after. I would prefer [Arimo](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Arimo), which is a free font that is metrically compatible with Arial. See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/text/mathtext.html#custom-fonts) for details on customising individual fonts for bold, calligraphic etc.

Alternatively you could use an external TeX renderer with

```
mpl.rc('text', usetex=True)
```

but you will need to supply the necessary LaTeX preamble to use Arial font.

Comment: Works! Thank you very much.
Works with Arial as well: 
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams["mathtext.fontset"] = 'custom'
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.rm']='Arial'