# Python matplotlib colorbar scientific notation base

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, contourf

I am trying to customise a colorbar on my matpllotlib contourf plots. Whilst I am able to use scientific notation I am trying to change the base of the notation - essentially so that my ticks would be in the range of (-100,100) rather than (-10,10).

For example, this produces a simple plot...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = (np.random.random((10,10)) - 0.5) * 0.2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot = ax.contourf(z)
cbar = fig.colorbar(plot)

cbar.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 0))
cbar.update_ticks()

plt.show()
```

like so:

[image]

However, I would like the label above the colorbar to be 1e-2 and the numbers to range from -10 to 10.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A possible solution can be to subclass the `ScalarFormatter` and fix the order of magnitude as in this question: [Set scientific notation with fixed exponent and significant digits for multiple subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656139/set-scientific-notation-with-fixed-exponent-and-significant-digits-for-multiple)

You would then call this formatter with the order of magnitude as the argument `order`, `OOMFormatter(-2, mathText=False)`. `mathText` is set to false to obtain the notation from the question, i.e. 
[image]
while setting it to True, would give [image].

You can then set the formatter to the colorbar via the colorbar's `format` argument.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

class OOMFormatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter):
    def __init__(self, order=0, fformat="%1.1f", offset=True, mathText=True):
        self.oom = order
        self.fformat = fformat
        matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter.__init__(self,useOffset=offset,useMathText=mathText)
    def _set_order_of_magnitude(self):
        self.orderOfMagnitude = self.oom
    def _set_format(self, vmin=None, vmax=None):
        self.format = self.fformat
        if self._useMathText:
             self.format = r'$\mathdefault{%s}$' % self.format


z = (np.random.random((10,10)) - 0.5) * 0.2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot = ax.contourf(z)
cbar = fig.colorbar(plot, format=OOMFormatter(-2, mathText=False))

plt.show()
```

[image]

For matplotlib versions < 3.1 the class needs to look like this:

```
class OOMFormatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter):
    def __init__(self, order=0, fformat="%1.1f", offset=True, mathText=True):
        self.oom = order
        self.fformat = fformat
        matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter.__init__(self,useOffset=offset,useMathText=mathText)
    def _set_orderOfMagnitude(self, nothing):
        self.orderOfMagnitude = self.oom
    def _set_format(self, vmin, vmax):
        self.format = self.fformat
        if self._useMathText:
            self.format = '$%s$' % matplotlib.ticker._mathdefault(self.format)
```

Comment: Can people still reproduce this?

Comment: @leb Yes I can reproduce it very well!

Comment: This is really useful! I ended up setting `fformat="%g"` in `__init__` though.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @ImportanceOfBeingErnes described, you could use a `FuncFormatter` ([docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter)) to which you just pass a function to determine the tick labels. This removes the auto generation of the `1e-2` header for your colorbar, but I imagine you can manually add that back in (I had trouble doing it, though was able to add it on the side). Using a `FuncFormatter`, you can just generate string tick values which has the advantage of not having to accept the way python thinks a number should be displayed.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tk

z = (np.random.random((10,10)) - 0.5) * 0.2

levels = list(np.linspace(-.1,.1,9))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot = ax.contourf(z, levels=levels)

def my_func(x, pos):
    label = levels[pos]
    return str(label*100)

fmt1 = tk.FuncFormatter(my_func)

cbar = fig.colorbar(plot, format=fmt1)
cbar.set_label("1e-2")

plt.show()
```

This will generate a plot which looks like this.

[image: Contour Plot]