# How to move the y axis scale factor to the position next to the y axis label?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some data plotted which I force to scientific notation to powers of 10 (instead of exponential). Heres a snippet of the code:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

formatter = mticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
formatter.set_powerlimits((-3,2))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

However, the scale factor of *x10^-4* appears on the top left hand corner of the graph.

Is there a simple method to force the position of this scale factor next to the y label as I have illustrated in the diagram below?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may set the offset to invisible, such that it does not appear in its original position.

```
ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
```

You may then get the offset from the formatter an update the label with it

```
offset = ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().get_offset()
ax.yaxis.set_label_text("original label" + " " + offset)
```

such that it appears inside the label.

The following automates this using a class with a callback, such that if the offset changes, it will be updated in the label.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

class Labeloffset():
    def __init__(self,  ax, label="", axis="y"):
        self.axis = {"y":ax.yaxis, "x":ax.xaxis}[axis]
        self.label=label
        ax.callbacks.connect(axis+'lim_changed', self.update)
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        self.update(None)

    def update(self, lim):
        fmt = self.axis.get_major_formatter()
        self.axis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
        self.axis.set_label_text(self.label + " "+ fmt.get_offset() )


x = np.arange(5)
y = np.exp(x)*1e-6

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y, marker="d")

formatter = mticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
formatter.set_powerlimits((-3,2))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

lo = Labeloffset(ax, label="my label", axis="y")


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How do you avoid calling draw inside the Labeloffset, and instead wait for a global draw command?

Comment: @komodovaran_ I do not avoid drawing the figure, instead I deliberately draw it to be able to apply the label change before showing it.

Comment: I mean, draw() inside Labeloffset adds a lot of overhead if applied to multiple dynamic axes in a GUI (in my case). Every other element of the canvas waits for a centralized draw(), but Labeloffset doesn't seem to respond to that.

Comment: If you anyways update your plot, you may just leave out the last two lines of the init method. Does that work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no. However, I found another solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517156/adjust-exponent-text-after-setting-scientific-limits-on-matplotlib-axis which involves grabbing the formatted exponent, and then inserting it into the label, then calling draw, which works perfectly.

Basically, `set_major_formatter()`, `offsetText.set_visible(False)`, `set_label_text(label + " (" + get_offset_text().get_text() + ")")`

Comment: @komodovaran_ But that is not dynamic at all, it will become wrong once you change the scale.

Comment: Tried posting a solution for a Qt GUI. Let me know if I've overlooked anything. It seems to work this way.

Comment: in my case i am getting an empty string when using `ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().get_offset()`. What could be the story here?

Comment: @RedSparrow That would be the case if there is no offset present in the first place I suppose. If this is a persisting problem, I would suggest to ask a new question with a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: **Update:** doing it in two steps solves the prolbem. First `ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter()` and then `.get_offset()`. Why could that be?

Comment: For me, even doing in two steps, it doesn't work. Is this a bug?

Comment: I think the empty string is because matplotlib has not yet computed the axis labels etc. The `Labeloffset` class posted in this answer includes a call to `ax.figure.canvas.draw()`, which must cause matplotlib to generate the offset label. I get an empty string from `get_offset()` unless I first call `ax.figure.canvas.draw()` (or `plt.gcf().canvas.draw()`, in my case), in which case `get_offset()` behaves as expected.

Comment: @komodovaran_ I had a similar requirement as yours: would prefer to only call the draw for all the plots at the end of all my data and plot processing code.

To solve this I added a callback that is called as soon as the figure is drawn at the end: 

fig.cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', on_first_draw)
fig.ax = ax
fig.drawcall_count=1

# with
def on_first_draw(event):
    fig = event.canvas.figure
    if fig.drawcall_count==1:
        fig.drawcall_count +=1
        update_xloclabel(fig.ax)

It is a bit messy, but does the job. Makes faster when processing many plots.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal example for a GUI, where `draw()` should only be called once per plot refresh. Keeps the correct scale factor. Can also be used with locked exponent, e.g. like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324152/python-matplotlib-colorbar-scientific-notation-base).

As an example I've just added a simple button to refresh the plot, but it could just as well be any other event.

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore # sorry about the Qt Creator mess
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
import numpy as np


class WidgetPlot(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.canvas = PlotCanvas(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.canvas)

class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, width = 5, height = 5, dpi = 100):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize = (width, height), dpi = dpi, tight_layout = True)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)

    def majorFormatterInLabel(self, ax, axis, axis_label, major_formatter):
        if axis == "x":
            axis = ax.xaxis
        if axis == "y":
            axis = ax.yaxis

        axis.set_major_formatter(major_formatter)
        axis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
        exponent = axis.get_offset_text().get_text()
        axis.set_label_text(axis_label + " (" + exponent + ")")


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(674, 371)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 601, 281))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.mpl_layoutBox = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.mpl_layoutBox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.mpl_layoutBox.setObjectName("mpl_layoutBox")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 300, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.w = WidgetPlot()
        self.canvas = self.w.canvas
        self.mpl_layoutBox.addWidget(self.w)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.refresh)



    def refresh(self):
        self.canvas.ax.clear()

        # Could've made it more beautiful. In any case, the cost of doing this is sub-ms.
        formatter = ScalarFormatter()
        formatter.set_powerlimits((-1, 1))
        self.canvas.majorFormatterInLabel(self.canvas.ax, "y", "label", major_formatter = formatter)

        r = np.random.choice((1e3, 1e5, 1e7, 1e9, 1e100))
        self.canvas.ax.plot(r)
        self.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    TraceWindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(TraceWindow)
    TraceWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This relies on a manual refresh (by pressing a button), right? In that case it's clearly a valid solution, but maybe not so ergonomic? I think that you could simply use my solution here as well, so this answer could benefit from stating the motivation of doing it differently than the existing answer.