# Format and location of exponent multiplier on y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've plotted the following graph:
[image]

but I want the `1e-4` to be something like LaTex formatting, and to be along the side. I've tried using
`ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True, useOffset=True))`

and
`ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_powerlimits((0,1))` separately, but they don't give the desired effect.

How can I make the y-axis look more "publishable"?

Comment: `...make the y-axis look more "publishable"` is pretty subjective.  Have you spent some time looking through the matplotlib documentation, tutorial and gallery?  Seems you need to figure out how to get the y axis to intersect the x axis where x = 0.

Comment: [Here](https://ga7g08.github.io/2015/07/22/Setting-nice-axes-labels-in-matplotlib/)  is a blog post about this problem, with the solution to move the exponent into the y axis label. Here you could simply multiply all data values by 10^6, and have a y axis range from 0 to ~251 J/sr (I find 200 J/sr more intuitive than 2E-4 MJ/sr, but I don't know what commonly done in astronomy).

Comment: This is also discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517156/adjust-exponent-text-after-setting-scientific-limits-on-matplotlib-axis with @user8153's blog post link adapting the SO answer. However, these sources leave the multiplier at the top of the y axis. See my answer for another way.

Comment: As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43216810/4124317) your approach seems correct. If you experience problems, it would be good to provide the exact code in use (or use the example from the linked answer) and a lot more details about versions of libraries etc.

Comment: I now marked as duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760763/how-to-move-the-y-axis-scale-factor-to-the-position-next-to-the-y-axis-label) which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score -1):

For a publication, I presume each graph is a one-time production rather than something that needs to be done programatically. In that case, you can assign strings to the tick labels by calling `set_yticklabels(a_list_of_strings)`. See https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#ticks-and-tick-labels .