# How to get multiplier string of scientific notation on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to get the text in the offset of the scientific notation of matplotlib, but `get_offset()` or `get_offset_text()` returns an empty string. I have checked these questions, but they didn't work:

[How to move the y axis scale factor to the position next to the y axis label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760763/how-to-move-the-y-axis-scale-factor-to-the-position-next-to-the-y-axis-label)

[Adjust exponent text after setting scientific limits on matplotlib axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517156/adjust-exponent-text-after-setting-scientific-limits-on-matplotlib-axis)

[prevent scientific notation in matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib-pyplot/28373421#28373421)

Here is a simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1,20)
y = np.exp(x)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.plot(x,y)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)) 

print(ax.yaxis.get_offset_text())
print(ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().get_offset())

fmt = ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter()
offset = ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().get_offset()
print(offset)


plt.show()
```

That generates:
[image]

I'd like to get the `x10^8`, but it returns only:

```
Text(0, 0.5, '')
```

The same happens if I don't use the ScalarFormatter. Am I missing something? Is there a separate function to get the multiplier (instead of the offset)?

**edit:** I'm currently using `Python 3.9.0` with `matplotlib 3.4.2` on a MacBook Pro, and I just run `python3 test.py`.

**edit2:** I have installed `Python 3.9.5`, and the solution with `fig.canvas.draw()` still does not work. The same with Linux works.

**edit3:** The problem happens when using the `MacOSX` backend. When changing to `TkAgg` or `Agg`, the get_offset works with the provided solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to draw the figure for the object to not hold some default values. From the source code on [`FigureCanvasBase.draw`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backend_bases.py#L2014):

```
"""
Render the `.Figure`.
It is important that this method actually walk the artist tree
even if not output is produced because this will trigger
deferred work (like computing limits auto-limits and tick
values) that users may want access to before saving to disk.
"""
```

Simply call `fig.canvas.draw()` and then `ax.yaxis.get_offset_text()` will have the updated values you want.

```py
x = np.arange(1, 20)
y = np.exp(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True))

fig.canvas.draw()
         
offset = ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().get_offset()
print(offset)
# $\times\mathdefault{10^{8}}\mathdefault{}$
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly: I have added `fig.canvas.draw()` below the `ax.plot`, but the `get_offset` and `get_offset_text` still return empty...

Comment: @Filipe The call to `draw()` should be after you've set the formatter, see the snippet I've added.

Comment: I have also tested that, and it still gives me blank! Can it be something on my installation? I'm using python 3.9.0 with matplotlib 3.4.2...

Comment: I am using py 3.9.2 and mpl 3.4.1, so I don't think it will be the versions. How are you plotting? Maybe update the question.

Comment: I have added, and it seems to be something with the version or the installation indeed: I have plotted in other machines, and I get the expected output! :/

Comment: Very strange: I have just installed Python 3.9.5, and it still doesn't print the offset on my mac (the same version on linux prints it). Anyway, I have tested my initial version, and the solution, and they still make sense, so I'll keep them, and also accept the answer. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Filipe Out of curiosity, what backend are you using? `maplotlib.get_backend()`. It could be that whatever backend inherits from `FigureCanvasBase` don't do the drawing properly. Does the offset still show correctly when you call `plt.show()`?

Comment: That's it! The default one is `MacOSX`... If I change to `TkAgg` or `Agg`, I do get the string `$\times\mathdefault{10^{8}}\mathdefault{}$`... 

Comment: @Filipe Aha! I got suspicious the moment you mentioned different machines. It's probably worthwhile submitting a bug ticket for that.

Comment: Thank you! I have edited (again) the question to explain the current issue.