# How to change the number of colorbar digits of the mantissa using offset notation

Tags: python, matplotlib, offset, colorbar, mantissa

I have a contour plot in matplotlib using a colorbar which is created by

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
divider = make_axes_locatable(axe) #adjust colorbar to fig height
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size=size, pad=pad)
cbar = f.colorbar(cf,cax=cax)
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_offset_position('left')
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=17)#28
t = cbar.ax.yaxis.get_offset_text()
t.set_size(15)
```

[image: Colorbar with offset]

How can I change the colorbar ticklabels (mantissa of exponent) showing up with only 2 digits after the '.' instead of 3 (keeping the off set notation)? Is there a possibility or do I have to set the ticks manually?

I have tried to use the str formatter

```
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.2g'))
```

so far but this doesn't give me the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that while the `FormatStrFormatter` allows to set the format precisely, it is not capable of handling offsets like the `1e-7` in the case from the question.

On the other hand the default `ScalarFormatter` automatically selects its own format, without letting the user change it. While this is mostly desireable, in this case, we want to specify the format ourself.

A solution is to subclass the `ScalarFormatter` and reimplement its `._set_format()` method, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43325107/4124317).

Note that you would want `"%.2f"` instead of `"%.2g"` to always show 2 digits after the decimal point.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

class FormatScalarFormatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter):
    def __init__(self, fformat="%1.1f", offset=True, mathText=True):
        self.fformat = fformat
        matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter.__init__(self,useOffset=offset,
                                                        useMathText=mathText)
    def _set_format(self, vmin, vmax):
        self.format = self.fformat
        if self._useMathText:
            self.format = '$%s$' % matplotlib.ticker._mathdefault(self.format)

z = (np.random.random((10,10))*0.35+0.735)*1.e-7

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot = ax.contourf(z, levels=np.linspace(0.735e-7,1.145e-7,10))

fmt = FormatScalarFormatter("%.2f")

cbar = fig.colorbar(plot,format=fmt)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank very much. I tried to built a minimal example but it showed always 2 digits as you said. This is exactly I was looking for, very nice.

Comment: This fails in a current version of matplotlib with `_set_format() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'vmin' and 'vmax'`

Comment: Additionally, `._mathdefault` no longer exists. This answer is no longer a viable solution.

Answer (score 3):

- Set the colorbar format during creation, by passing [`matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter) to the `format=` parameter.

```
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2023)
z = (np.random.random((10,10))*0.35+0.735)*1.e-7

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))

p1 = ax.contourf(z, levels=np.linspace(0.735e-7, 1.145e-7, 10))

# compare the formats of the two colorbars
cb1 = fig.colorbar(p1, format=tkr.FormatStrFormatter('%.9f'))
cb1.set_label('%.9f', labelpad=-40, y=1.05, rotation=0)

cb2 = fig.colorbar(p1, format=tkr.FormatStrFormatter('%.2g'))
cb2.set_label('%.2g', labelpad=-40, y=1.05, rotation=0)
```

[image]

- The colorbar can also be formatted after creation.

```py
cb1 = fig.colorbar(p1)
cb1.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tkr.FormatStrFormatter('%.9f'))
cb1.set_label('%.2g', labelpad=-40, y=1.05, rotation=0)
```