# matplotlib tick label format: fixed number of digits with offset

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way in matplotlib that I can specify the number of digits to be used in the tick labels of an axis when there is a common exponent?

To be more specific, I have ticks on y-axis at `[-3e-5, 0.0, 3e-5]`, and I want the label to be shown as `-3.0`, `0.0`, `3.0` with the common factor `1e-5` shown at the top left outside. My matplotlib sets these labels as `-3`, `0`, and `3` by omitting `.0` from the string.

I tried `using matplotlib.ticker.FormatStrFormatter` as in this answer,
[A. Matplotlib: Specify format of floats for tick lables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29188910/883431)

like,

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.1f'))
```

but then I can't get the common factor `1e-5`.

I tried using

```
matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useOffset=True)
```

to get the common factor, but then it looks I can specify the number of digits to be shown.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You will want to use the `FormatScalarFormatter` I invented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45816969/4124317) and apply it to your axis. `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatScalarFormatter("%.1f"))`. If you have a problem with implementation, a complete code would be needed.

Comment: If you also want to fix the offset, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656139/set-scientific-notation-with-fixed-exponent-and-significant-digits-for-multiple).