# How to multiply axis tick values by factors of 10 in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I would like to multiply my y-axis ticks (as you can see below) so that instead of 0.25 to 2 they show a range of values from 2500 up to 20000.

How do I do that?

[image: desired output]

Comment: Look at change the y offset in matplotlib.  That '1e7' above the y axis is the offset.

Comment: Your current y-axis is actually 0.25*1e7 to 2.00*1e7. Are you saying you want it to display 2500*1e3 to 20000*1e3?

Comment: `plt.plot(x,y/1000)`

Comment: @tdy Yes thats exactly what I'd like to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set scientific notation with fixed exponent and significant digits for multiple subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42656139/set-scientific-notation-with-fixed-exponent-and-significant-digits-for-multiple)