# how to round-off the value of the x-axis in python line chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

how to round off the value of the x-axis in this graph as it's very long number 6000000 and not looking good. and also how can I make this graph more good-looking and presentable

here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import numpy as np 
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 16})
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='x', useOffset=False)
df = pd.read_csv("Z:/a.csv", delimiter=",")
plt.plot(df['A'], df['B'], marker='.', linewidth= 2, )
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('MM')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 20+1, 2))
plt.show()
```

My graph looks like this
[image]

however, I need to round-off y-axis like this
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify format of floats for tick labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29188757/specify-format-of-floats-for-tick-labels)

Comment: there are many threads available but i am not able to adopt it according to my code

Comment: Use scientific notation like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577665/change-x-axes-scale-in-matplotlib) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371674/prevent-scientific-notation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change x axes scale in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577665/change-x-axes-scale-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Use [ax.ticklabel_format](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html)

```
...
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# set the format BEFORE putting "ink" in the figure
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', scilimits=(4,4), useMathText=True)
ax.set_ylim((57800,62200))
...
```

---

This is exactly (oh well! almost...) the first diagram in question, but with the *y*-axis labels as in the second diagram in the question.

```
In [77]: from numpy import array, nan
    ...: from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, show
    ...: from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
    ...: 
    ...: y = 10**4*array((nan,20,4,6,8,6,4,25,65,38,40,18,16,4,30,64,35,38,19,13,4))
    ...: fig, ax = subplots()
    ...: ax.plot(y*200)
    ...: ax.set_xticks(range(0, 20+1, 2));
    ...: ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(200000))
    ...: ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', scilimits=((5,5)), useMathText=True)
    ...: show()
```

[image]

Comment: the problem i am facing is integrating it with my code... i saw the different solution

Comment: In which respect do you think my code cannot be integrated with yours? Further, could you please explain what do you mean with _"i saw the different solution"_? I really do not understand...